# Send DataMap to Android Wear when App is closed

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os

I am trying to send a DataMap to my Android Wear app when it is not open, but I do not have any idea to do that. Could someone explain me how to do? 
Thanks so much, kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService) which runs in the background, even when the app is closed.

I'd also suggest reading the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) for android wear.

Comment: Thank you for your time.